Borb text triggers "AssertionError: A Rectangle must have a non-negative width."
I am interested to change the font of some text that is in documents.
I used the #581-filtering-by-font example and added re-submitting to SimpleFindReplace and it is triggering the assertion that a rectangle cannot have a negative width.
I have confirmed the initial font 'VFMBOX+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman' is in the document.
Borb version 2.1.25
Python version - 3.11
This is the code -
*`#!chapter_005/src/snippet_017.py
import typing

from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit import FontNameFilter
from borb.toolkit import SimpleTextExtraction
from borb.toolkit import SimpleFindReplace

def main():

    # create FontNameFilter
    l0: FontNameFilter = FontNameFilter("VFMBOX+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman")

    # filtered text just gets passed to SimpleTextExtraction
    l1: SimpleTextExtraction = SimpleTextExtraction()
    l0.add_listener(l1)

    # read the Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    with open("C:\Data\PDFFontChange\PD-1239-G_RevA_PR.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l0])

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    templist = (l1.get_text()[0]).splitlines()
    # print(templist)
    i = 0 
    for x in templist :
        print(i, ' : ', x)
        i += 1
        doc = SimpleFindReplace.sub(x, x, doc, repl_font="Helvetica")

    # store
    with open("output2.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Here is the full error traceback & I have included the first numbered (printed as 0 : ) text found by the FontNameFilter from the PDF that is resubmitted by the code into the SimpleFindReplace that triggers the error.
0  :  At the heart of your pump or dispenser,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\Glenn_Begin\PDF_Workings\BORB_PDF_FontNameAlterTrajan.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Python\Glenn_Begin\PDF_Workings\BORB_PDF_FontNameAlterTrajan.py", line 36, in main
    doc = SimpleFindReplace.sub(x, x, doc, repl_font="Helvetica")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Glenn_Begin\.venv\Lib\site-packages\borb\toolkit\text\simple_find_replace.py", line 72, in sub
    ] = RegularExpressionTextExtraction.get_matches_for_pdf(pattern, doc)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Glenn_Begin\.venv\Lib\site-packages\borb\toolkit\text\regular_expression_text_extraction.py", line 375, in get_matches_for_pdf
    CanvasStreamProcessor(page, Canvas(), []).read(page_source, [cse])
  File "C:\Python\Glenn_Begin\.venv\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\canvas_stream_processor.py", line 277, in read
    raise e
  File "C:\Python\Glenn_Begin\.venv\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\canvas_stream_processor.py", line 271, in read
    operator.invoke(self, operands, event_listeners)
  File "C:\Python\Glenn_Begin\.venv\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\operator\text\show_text_with_glyph_positioning.py", line 84, in invoke
    l._event_occurred(tri)
  File "C:\Python\Glenn_Begin\.venv\Lib\site-packages\borb\toolkit\text\regular_expression_text_extraction.py", line 326, in _event_occurred
    self._render_text(event)
  File "C:\Python\Glenn_Begin\.venv\Lib\site-packages\borb\toolkit\text\regular_expression_text_extraction.py", line 338, in _render_text
    for e in text_render_info.split_on_glyphs():
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Glenn_Begin\.venv\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\event\chunk_of_text_render_event.py", line 177, in split_on_glyphs
    e._baseline_bounding_box = Rectangle(
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Glenn_Begin\.venv\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\geometry\rectangle.py", line 30, in __init__
    assert width >= 0, "A Rectangle must have a non-negative width."
           ^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: A Rectangle must have a non-negative width.


The error is coming from deep within borb and doesn't appear to have anything to do with a parameter you passed in.  Not sure what could be done.

Thanks Mark, I've noticed jorisschellekens the creator of borb in some other posts so he may have insight.

If you want to try and solve it yourself, I believe the error is in this part of the package. You'll have to print the width related stuff to figure out what is going on. https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb/blob/3ee59f6226801b3c9b64650a6e1117f30e24479b/borb/toolkit/text/simple_find_replace.py#L94

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/10292330/oystershucker,
I took a limited shot at that - found that in SimpleFindReplace it succeeds to get the number_of_pages but fails somewhere when calculating matches_per_page I think in class PDFMatch: which has a fair bit of subtracting in width fields which perhaps goes negative at some point.
There's a lot more logic to understand there to find the issue which I can't do right now.
